# Home back exercises without equipment

Tags: exercise, muscle, training, exercise-technique, back

What exercises can be done anywhere with no equipment, not even a bar for the upper back muscles and is as easy to learn as a bodyweight push up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possibilities:

1. Pull ups could be your best bet. I suppose you mean "no equipment" as in no weights or rowers or barbells, etc. I'm not including such things as towels, gloves, cloth, in this list.
2. The Superman Exercise: Check out this [link](https://www.bodybuilding.com/exercises/superman) for more detail. If you *really really* want no equipment, this is probably the only thing that works. You don't even need to have clothes on to do it :P.
3. I could go on to list many more, but I'll save you the reading and just immediately direct you to this link. Normally, exercises that are body-weight oriented don't really require equipment. Check this [link](http://blog.52challenges.com/workout/best-bodyweight-exercises-for-the-back-vol-2-upper-back-strength-stretching/) out!

*Does this answer your question?*

Comment: Small tidbit: The superman exercise is more of a lower back / abs exercise, and won't do anything for upper back which OP asked for.

Comment: @Tas okay thanks :P I didn't realize